# SSH "kex_exchange_identification" error after macOS update

Tags: macos, ssh, connection, updates

Nothing else changed at the server side. However, after my recent MacOS update, I am getting k**ex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer**

Searched around and around and could not fix it. Please help. Thanks.

```
ssh xxxx@xx.xx.x.xx -Tv    
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.x.xx [xx.xx.x.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chaowu/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se], [apple.se], or [su]. When you do, clarify what host was upgraded--the host that you're running ssh on? or the host that you're connecting to?

Answer (score 3):

I found the root cause for this error on macOS Catalina being the computer to which you SSH connect. There is some sort of bug in the Catalina upgrades and possibly patches. Be sure you check permissions on the OpenSSH generated public / private key files in /etc/ssh on the Mac system you are trying to connect to with SSH. These keys are used by the SSH daemon.

Since OpenSSH is cross platform the same would apply to any operating system running SSHd. These files must have the proper permissions.

/etc/ssh is the default path but if you are on Windows or other OS it may vary. But for most Unix/Linux/macOS systems it should be /etc/ssh.

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/ssh/*_key
sudo chmod 644 /etc/ssh/*.pub
```

You should also verify that the SSH client has the correct permissions on the ~/.ssh and the public / private keys, config, authorized_keys, etc. Although if these are wrong you will be told right away there is a permissions problem. But when the permissions on keys for the SSH daemon are wrong you receive errors in the logs. Not counting the public keys used for SSH password free sign on.

When it's not DNS nor certificates, then it's always permissions.